# isNullOrEmpty doesn't return the expected value

Tags: android, kotlin

I have been using the following code to check if the value of a variable is not null or "". But since I used the value.isNullOrEmpty() method. The condition doesn't function as expected. Is the result of isNullOrEmpty() not same as the following code? I would love to here from you!

```
fun isNullOrBlank(str: String?): Boolean {
            return str == null || str == ""
        }
```

Comment: perahps it should be str==null || str.length==0 ? can you give a specific example where it does not work and in what way it fails?

Comment: what's the result? always true or always false?

Comment: Please specify your input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the official documentation, isNullOrEmpty() is described as:

> isNullOrEmpty
>   fun CharSequence?.isNullOrEmpty(): Boolean Returns true if this
>   nullable char sequence is either null or empty.

So this should returns true as your function isNullOrBlank.

Btw the function isNullOrBlank already exists, see [the documentation here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-null-or-blank.html), in addition to check if a String is null or empty, it also checks if the string is not filled with whitespaces. It may helps you to handle more cases.